# How to catch input on document[keypress] on window in javascript from Zebra mc330m scanner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode

I configured the scanner to send Enter at the end of the input and js reads it correctly but the other characters are lost.

I have tried to decode the input characters with **event.keyCode, event.which, event.charCode** and nothing works. If I attach it to normal input it works.
It also works in the browser address bar (chrome). But when I attach it to the document['onkeypress'] it doesn't read the characters.

I tried Martin Orth solution from here: https://developer.zebra.com/thread/35513
but I couldn't make it work I even don't know if it's the same scanner.

From here I understood that the scanner is sending ASCII characters and javascript has no mechanizm to read them?
https://developer.zebra.com/thread/34536

If anyone knows the solution to this problem, help is highly appreciated. I prefer with js/jquery if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature, using keypress, was recently added to DataWedge 7.3 which is included in the latest MC33 OS update (02.13.15 - LG Update 16) - I wrote a blog about how to use it: https://developer.zebra.com/blog/listening-keypress-events-datawedge.  For clarity, I work for Zebra

Comment: Thanks for your support Darryn! This is the real solution!

Answer (score 4):

What this code does is it creates an input focuses on it, but absolutely positions off screen becacuse IE has a problem with focusing on hidden text fields. Then detects changes to the input and outputs that for now to console.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".scanner-input").focus().on("input",function(){
          let barcode = $(this).val();
          console.log(barcode);
          $(this).val("");
     }).blur(function(){
         $(this).focus();
     });
});
```

```css
.scanner-input{position:absolute;left:-10000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="scanner-input">
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately the users will need to scan multiple barcodes not only one so with input located outside the visible screen on the mobile device they will have a very hard time to get back and focus it again

Comment: @marto, I made a slight modification which will allow this. Basically, after you grab the barcode, it empties the input field and they can scan again. I also updated the code so if the input loses focus, it will be given focus.

Comment: This is a really good answer.  As you can see by those forum posts, some device browsers allow you to read onKeyPress from the DOM but not all devices whereas this method should work reliably on *all* devices.  You could use Zebra's Enterprise Browser or a hybrid framework to achieve the same with more control but I don't have a better suggestion than this answer for a pure Chrome-based solution, at least until Zebra make some changes to DataWedge to allow this to work.  For clarity, I work for Zebra.