# keypress event for handling scanner input returns only first character

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode-scanner

I am using Datalogic Heron scanner for bar-code input and using this code for getting the barcode value -

```
<input type="text" id="scannerBarcode" />
```

and

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        alert(e.key);
        $("#scannerBarcode").val(e.key);
        e.preventDefault();
        });      
</script>
```

I am getting two issues -

1. Using e.key only returning the first character. I don't know how to capture the complete bar-code value. When I have the focus on a simple txt file then barcode shows whole value.
2. The alert flashes and doesn't wait for me to click OK.

This is my first day with any scanner, so please bear if this is a silly question.

Can anyone please guide how to fix above.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to catch key presses on the entire document, not just the input?

Comment: change `alert(e.key)` to `console.log(e.key)` to see what happens with no blocking alert windows during the `keypress` events (and to see the results in the console window)

Comment: because they typically fire multiple events, not just one. Never debug with alert.....

Comment: The problem is barcode scanners are standard keyboard inputs, but without sending that value to an input field, you won't get the entire string as you noticed.

You can try my answer in regards to the zebra (the same issue) https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769272/3684265

Comment: yes, I was trying to capture keypress for whole doc as the input textbox may/may not have the focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is barcode scanners are standard keyboard inputs, but without sending that value to an input field, you won't get the entire string as you noticed. You can try my answer in regards to the zebra (the same issue) https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769272/3684265

Another option in keeping with your existing code, is DON'T alert instead `APPEND` to the barcode value on each `keypress`.

```js
var barcode = document.querySelector("#scannerBarcode");
document.addEventListener("keypress",function(e){
   if(e.keyCode != 13){
       barcode.value += e.key;
   }
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="scannerBarcode">
```

Answer (score 2):

For a barcode input managed by a global document keypress event, you may expect a burst of keyboard events when reading a barcode, so you need to store the characters and clear them between new scans. This code will let you append characters coming from a quick sequence of inputs, and clean it for a new scan.

```js
var scannerInput ="";
var lastClear=0;
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        console.log(e.key);
        clearTimeout(lastClear);
        lastClear=window.setTimeout(function(){
           scannerInput="";
        },500);
        scannerInput+=e.key;        
        $("#scannerBarcode").val(scannerInput);
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="scannerBarcode" type="text">
```

You don't need to focus the text input. Any group of keys pressed in a quick sequence will be captured (the same way as you receive data from a barcode).

If you barcode scanner uses Carriage Return (`'Enter'` key) to finish, you can clear the scannerInput variable when `e.Key = 'Enter'`, instead of a timeout